# Navigation controller with tab bar controller of navigation controller

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a navigation controller, and its root view controller is a tab bar controller. In this tab bar controller I have two view controllers like this:

[image]

In the tab bar controller I have a custom navigation bar.
When I click the first item in tab bar, the navigation bar  looks good
 but when I click the second, I have a problem: below the navigation bar there is another navigation bar with red color.
Can some explain this for me?

Comment: you have problem with color of navigation bar

Comment: Yes you have to hide the root navigation controller. appdelegate.window.rootviewcontroller get navigation bar reference and hide it

Comment: thank you, but while when i clike to first item, the navigation bar it not green color, but when i clike to second item it is red color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want navigation bar of first navigation controller then from the interface builder (storyboard) select your root navigation controller (i.e. navigationcontroller that's embed with tabbarcontroller) and from `attribute inspector` uncheck `shows navigation bar` under `Navigation controller`! This will hide navigation bar for root navigation view controller!!

In your case you should hide and show navigation bar in `viewWillDisAppear` and `viewWillAppear` something like,

In `viewWillAppear`

```
   self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
```

In `viewWillDisAppear`

```
   self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```

Do above things for your both viewcontroller of your tabbarcontroller!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do `navigationController.navigationBarHidden = true` on the root navigation controller, or the child whatever suits you.

But the better will be if you use only one `UINavigationController`, and IMO `navigationController` of `UITabBarController` only.